# Why am I unable to use advanced aggregation features with a multiple insert clause in Hive?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I would like to use a multiple insert clause with the advanced aggregation feature `with cube` to insert multiple aggregated values into a single table in Hive.
However, for an unknown reason the subtotals of the set of columns are not inserted.

This problem occurs both when the default value of null for the column value is used, and when it is replaced with a string using `coalesce`.
There are no null values that could cause conflict in any column.
This problem also occurs with other advanced aggregation features (`grouping sets`, `rollup`).
I wish to use this method of insertion because it would be the most efficient manner of performing this operation.

The syntax I am using is:

```
FROM tablename1
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE tablename2 PARTITION (partcol1=val1) SELECT select_statement1 WHERE where_condition1 GROUP BY col_list WITH CUBE
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE tablename2 PARTITION (partcol1=val2) SELECT select_statement2 WHERE where_condition2 GROUP BY col_list WITH CUBE ...;
```

Is there a way to resolve this problem, or is it not possible to use a multiple insert clause in this way?

Thank you for your assistance in advance.

Comment: James Why don't you use dynamic partition..?

Comment: In this case there are two reasons why dynamic partitions are not used.
1. The table contains two partitions, one of which is defined within the where conditions of each insert clause and so the value must be set manually.
2. The execution environment of the batch query requires that static partitions be used.

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears to specific to the Map-reduce execution engine. The above syntax is executed properly when the execution engine is changed to Tez.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-15581